# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined in vuejs

Tags: vuejs2

in vue js when i want to import owl-carousel it give me the the error 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined'[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iq3of.png)
[dependencies pic in which owl-carousel is added[][2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkzK1.png)

Comment: with placing one error image nobody can help you! upload your project into sandbox then people can help you better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you are importing owl-carousel from a cdn which had caused me similar problem. Have you tried this [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-owl-carousel)?